# Filter object of object based on value js

Tags: javascript

I have this object of objects, I am trying to get the items which include a social

```js
const events = {
    'event-1': { id: 'event-1', channel: 'facebook'},
    'event-2': { id: 'event-2', channel: 'twitter'},
    'event-3': { id: 'event-3', channel: 'slack'},
  };
```

I need to get for example event that has `facebook` and slack
Any ideas how filter works on `javascript` for objects not array?

Thank you

Comment: Any reason you're using an object instead of an array?

Comment: I need to filter from events object, I am doing sorting, so I need when I check facebook to get events that have facebook

Answer (score 5):

You can turn it to entries, filter them, and turn it back to an object:

```js
const events = {
    'event-1': { id: 'event-1', channel: 'facebook'},
    'event-2': { id: 'event-2', channel: 'twitter'},
    'event-3': { id: 'event-3', channel: 'slack'},
  }
  
const result = Object.fromEntries( 
    Object.entries(events).filter( ([key,value]) => value.channel == "facebook" || value.channel == "slack")
);

console.log(result);
```

You can check a list of channels by putting them in an array and using `includes`

```js
const events = {
    'event-1': { id: 'event-1', channel: 'facebook'},
    'event-2': { id: 'event-2', channel: 'twitter'},
    'event-3': { id: 'event-3', channel: 'slack'},
  }
  
const channels = ["facebook","slack"];
const result = Object.fromEntries( 
    Object.entries(events).filter( ([key,value]) => channels.includes(value.channel))
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: is there a way instead of value.channel || value.channel  to do it something like value.channel = ['facebook', 'twitter']

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
const events = {
            'event-1': { id: 'event-1', channel: 'facebook' },
            'event-2': { id: 'event-2', channel: 'twitter' },
            'event-3': { id: 'event-3', channel: 'slack' },
        };
        
var val = Object.values(events).filter(t=>t.channel == 'facebook' || t.channel == 'slack');

console.log(val);
```

Comment: thanks, what if I want to include facebook + slack I tried ['facebook', 'slack'] but no luck

Comment: @lilo Just use `||` operator. you know `filter` needs Boolean expression, So you can use `||` or `includes`.  I updated my answer

Comment: @lilo if you want to use `['facebook', 'slack']` you can use this way: `Object.values(events).filter(t => ['facebook', 'slack'].includes(t.channel));`

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a separate variable that holds all the social platforms and filter events array based on that...

```
const socialPlatforms = [
  'facebook',
  'slack'
];

const events = {
  'event-1': { id: 'event-1', channel: 'facebook'},
  'event-2': { id: 'event-2', channel: 'twitter'},
  'event-3': { id: 'event-3', channel: 'slack'},
};

const socialEvents = Object.values(events)
  .filter(event => socialPlatforms.includes(event.channel))
  .map(event => event.id);

console.log(socialEvents);

/*

[ 'event-1', 'event-3' ]

*/
```